# How to make recursively nested array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

Below is the json I have:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "characteristics": [
        {
            "name": "A",
            "description": "",
            "comprisedOf": [
                {
                    "name": "A1",
                    "description": "",
                    "comprisedOf": [
                        {
                            "name": "A1.1",
                            "description": "",
                            "value": "10"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "A1.2",
                            "description": "",
                            "value": "5"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "A2",
                    "description": "",
                    "value": "100"
                },
                {
                    "name": "A3",
                    "description": "",
                    "value": "20"
                },
                {
                    "name": "A4",
                    "description": "",
                    "value": "50"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "B",
            "description": "",
            "value": "10"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here I have 2 characteristics object of "test" - A and B.These 2 objects may or may not have "comprisedOf" array. For Eg A has"comprisedOf" array whereas B has not. These comprisedOf array further may or may not have comprisedof objects array.

Now i have to make an array out of this which should be like the given below array:-

```
[
    {
        "name": "test",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "A",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name":"A1",
                        "children:: [
                            {
                                "name":  "A1.1"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "A1.2"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "A2"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "A3"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "A4"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "B"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How this array can be formed recursively out of the first array?

Thanks so much!!

EDIT:- Here's what I have tried:-

```
var makeChildrenAll = function(dataChar){
    dataChar.forEach(function(char){
        if(char.comprisedOf) {
            makeChildrenAll(char.comprisedOf);                                
        }
        childrenData.push({
            name: char.name,
            description: char.description,
           children: childrenData
        });
    });
};
makeChildrenAll(dataChar);
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. The objective here is for people to help you fix **your code** when it doesn't work as expected

Comment: @charlietfl Edited my answer for what I have tried

Comment: There's no such thing as a *"JSON object"* - JSON is always a **string**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be recursive you want the function to return and be able to assign that return to current object

Something like

```js
function mapItems(arr){
   // return new array
   return arr.reduce((a,c)=>{
     var newObj={name:c.name};
     if(Array.isArray(c.comprisedOf)){
        // use returned array of recursive function to assign to `children` property
        newObj.children = mapItems(c.comprisedOf)
     }
     return a.concat(newObj)
   },[])
}

console.log(mapItems(data.characteristics))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important;}
```

```html
<script>
var data ={
    "name": "test",
    "characteristics": [
        {
            "name": "A",
            "description": "",
            "comprisedOf": [
                {
                    "name": "A1",
                    "description": "",
                    "comprisedOf": [
                        {
                            "name": "A1.1",
                            "description": "",
                            "value": "10"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "A1.2",
                            "description": "",
                            "value": "5"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "A2",
                    "description": "",
                    "value": "100"
                },
                {
                    "name": "A3",
                    "description": "",
                    "value": "20"
                },
                {
                    "name": "A4",
                    "description": "",
                    "value": "50"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "B",
            "description": "",
            "value": "10"
        }
    ]
}
</script>
```

Comment: any other way to solve this up? Something like in my approach,  have used recursive many times, but i m not able to use it here

Comment: Not sure how much simpler it can get than what I did here. Could use `map()` instead of `reduce()` I guess

Comment: Unfortunately, map and reduce function does not work in my js version.could you please modify it

Comment: Huh? If `forEach` works no reason `map()` or `reduce()` shouldn't work. What environment are you working in?

Comment: This is an internal js framework, giving me the syntax error in reduce function."Unexpected token >"

Comment: Oh I know what it probably is. I used es6 arrow function. Change `arr.reduce((a,c)=>{` to `arr.reduce(function(a,c){` for ES5 compatability

Comment: Thanks you so much. It works now and getting the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a different start array and use a destructuring for the wanted properties.

```js
function mapItems(array) {
    return array.map(({ name, comprisedOf }) =>
        Object.assign({ name }, comprisedOf && { children: mapItems(comprisedOf) }));
}

var data = { name: "test", characteristics: [{ name: "A", description: "", comprisedOf: [{ name: "A1", description: "", comprisedOf: [{ name: "A1.1", description: "", value: "10" }, { name: "A1.2", description: "", value: "5" }] }, { name: "A2", description: "", value: "100" }, { name: "A3", description: "", value: "20" }, { name: "A4", description: "", value: "50" }] }, { name: "B", description: "", value: "10" }] };

console.log(mapItems([{ name: data.name, comprisedOf: data.characteristics }]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES5

```js
function mapItems(array) {
    return array.map(function (o) {
        var r = { name: o.name };
        if (o.comprisedOf) {
            r.children = mapItems(o.comprisedOf);
        }
        return r;
    });
}

var data = { name: "test", characteristics: [{ name: "A", description: "", comprisedOf: [{ name: "A1", description: "", comprisedOf: [{ name: "A1.1", description: "", value: "10" }, { name: "A1.2", description: "", value: "5" }] }, { name: "A2", description: "", value: "100" }, { name: "A3", description: "", value: "20" }, { name: "A4", description: "", value: "50" }] }, { name: "B", description: "", value: "10" }] };

console.log(mapItems([{ name: data.name, comprisedOf: data.characteristics }]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```